# CSS grid not rendering the same on firefox and chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-grid

Here is the code snippet : https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-stallman-p71018

My css grid does not render in the same way on firefox and chrome, despite the fact that the computed rules are the same on both browsers.

The computed height of the grid is the same value on both browsers, and the code for the grid template is the same as well :

```css
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: [col0] 33% [col1] 17% [col2] 25% [col3] 12.5% [col4] 12.5% [col5];
    grid-template-rows: [row0] 50% [row1] 33% [row2] 17% [row3];
```

There is no problem on firefox :
[image]

But on chrome, the rows take a different height:
[image]

I tried to change the parent's height of the grid, and obtained an unpleasant result (the row still took too much height making white space, even when the height stop the right place).
[image]

I tried to check if the computed rules were the same on both browsers, and they are.

Comment: Please could you include a runnable snippet in your question which shows the problem as it's impossible to guess what the problem might be just from the pictures. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just added the code sample runnable on code sandbox, in the beginning of the post

Comment: Please include the code in your question - otherwise it might become useless to future readers when the sandbox disappears.